# How can I simulate keystrokes in a Google Script App?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, keyboard

I need to simulate a keyboard in Google Script Apps (like `SendKeys` in C#).
For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, or any other shortcut or button.

Is there any function or library for this in Google Script Apps?  If not, what external library could I use?

Comment: You want to use scripts to activate the Sheets / Docs UI menus? No can do. Why not share what you're actually trying to automate, since a lot of the UI features can be done programmatically.